# Enable Ehcache caching for Axon Sagas

Tags: ehcache, saga, axon

My goal is to create 2 caches with the newCacheManagerBuilder() API and store them off-heap

My understanding is that i need one cache for the Saga instances and one for the Associations. First I'm initializing the cache manager.

```
    @Bean
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        CacheManager cacheManager =  CacheManagerBuilder.newCacheManagerBuilder().build();
        cacheManager.init();
        return cacheManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public org.ehcache.Cache<String, MySaga> sagaEhcache(CacheManager cacheManager) {
        return cacheManager.createCache("sagaEhcache",
            CacheConfigurationBuilder.newCacheConfigurationBuilder(
                String.class,
                MySaga.class,
                ResourcePoolsBuilder.newResourcePoolsBuilder().offheap(sagaCacheOffHeapMb, MemoryUnit.MB)
            ).build()
        );
    }

    @Bean
    public org.ehcache.Cache<String, AssociationValue> sagaAssocEhcache(CacheManager cacheManager) {
        return cacheManager.createCache("sagaAssocEhcache",
            CacheConfigurationBuilder.newCacheConfigurationBuilder(
                String.class,
                AssociationValue.class,
                ResourcePoolsBuilder.newResourcePoolsBuilder().offheap(sagaAssocCacheOffHeapMb, MemoryUnit.MB)
            ).build()
        );
    }
```

Are the mentioned mappings correct: String/MySaga and String/AssociationValue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Axon Framework uses the notion of a cache adapters to utilize caches for things like the `CachingSagaStore` or `CachingEventSourcingRepository`.
Both require an Axon implementation of `Cache`, which can be traversed back to allowing you to use either a `JCacheAdapter` or `EhCacheAdapter`.
As you are using EhCache, you would be required to use the `EhCacheAdapter` in your set up.

There is however one drawback with your setup.
You are using [`org.ehcache`](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.ehcache), thus version 3. Axon Framework however uses [`net.sf.ehcache`](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:net.sf.ehcache), thus version 2.
So, unless there is some mechanism to revert EhCache version 3 to version 2, you will be required to actually downgrade the EhCache version in your application for now.

---

**Update**

As shown in the comments, you've implemented your own `EhCacheAdapter` to support the latest version of EhCache with Axon Framework. This thus leaves you with the following question:

> Are the mentioned mappings correct: String/MySaga and String/AssociationValue?

Checking the `CachingSagaStore` implementation, you can see an `CacheEntry<S>` is used for the Saga and a `Set<String>` for the associations. The generic `S` stands for the Saga implementation, thus `MySaga` in your example.

---

**Update 2**

For a sample project leveraging Axon Framework together with version 2 of EhCache, you can check out the [Axon Trader](https://github.com/AxonFramework/Axon-trader/) application.

Comment: thanks for the reply, it is correct. In this regard, I have created my own EhCacheAdapter, which implements the Cache interface from org.axonframework.common.caching and which I think it should work. I'm more concerned about the actual mappings String/MySaga and String/AssociationValue. Are they correct ?

Comment: Aah alright, you got that covered then; great! If you would have the time, an contribution to Axon Framework to support the latest EhCache would be much appreciated!
For you question at hand though, the `CachingSagaStore` uses an `Entry<S>` for the Saga and a `Set<String>` for the associations.
Let me add this to my answer too.

Comment: So that means that the mappings (keyType/valueType) should be String/MySaga (for the sagaEhcache) and String/String (for the sagaAssocEhcache) ?

Comment: Sorry for no being specific enough. I believe that's correct @sodomark. To be entirely honest with you though, I haven't set up caching for Sagas recently, so my knowledge has slipped a little on the matter. Hence why I referred to "what the code does".
I would however assume t hat { String - MySaga }  and { String - String} as what you should be going for when it comes to the Saga and Association Value cache respectively.

Comment: after some more research it seems that the mappings should be String/Entry and String/Set. But because I need to store the caches off heap, I need them Serializable so the mappings should be changed to String/CacheEntry and String/HashSet. The issue right now is that CacheEntry class (inner class of CachingSagaStore) is private. Also, do you have a link for a EhCache version 2 implementation example ?

Comment: Ah, so EhCache does expect it in that form. I had a hunch, but like I said it's been sometime that I've set up caching...sorry for the misdirection there.
If you want to utilize/access the `CacheEntry`, you'll then likely have to provide your own `CacheEntry` copy or maybe even the `CachingSagaStore` to be able to set everything up correctly. Seems like a useful feature request to Axon Framework to be honest.
Lastly, I'll update my original response with a sample project using EhCache for you.